# One sentence seems to be two sentences

Tags: sentence-structure, optional-that

There seem to be 2 sentences in the following.
" He recently noticed something abnormal about the way this present generation of teens is developing."
"He recently noticed something abnormal about the way" & "this present generation of teens is developing". 
May I add "that" between two parts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you certainly can!

> He recently noticed something abnormal about the way **that** this present generation of teens is developing.

However, 'that' is often not used between two sentences (independent clauses) when the meaning is perfectly clear. Also correct:

> He recently noticed something abnormal about the way this present generation of teens is developing.